# Kendo UI getByUid() not working in hierarchical data source

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik

I have a Kendo UI hierarchical data source set up, but getByUid() does not work as expected for me. It returns 'undefined' when I search for a uid that I can see is in my hierarchical data source.

The twist is that I am searching for a node that I add after initially setting up the hierarchical data source, using the .data() method.

Here is a Kendo Dojo snippet to illustrate - you will see at the bottom I console.log the datasource, the uid I am searching for, and the response ('undefined'), so you can see that that uid is in there.

[Kendo Dojo Snippet](http://dojo.telerik.com/AwenU)

I think I have set up my schemas and models correctly, and as far as I can tell from the Kendo documentation I should be able to populate the dataSource using .data() and populate it with a fresh JavaScript object, with more nested nodes, yet still I cannot search for these new nodes using getByUid().

Here is the JavaScript from the Dojo snippet as well:

```
var initColumns = [
  {
    id: 0,
    Index: 0,
    ResponsiveStyle: 3,
    Widgets: []
  },    
  { 
    id: 1,
    Index: 1,
    ResponsiveStyle: 3,
    Widgets:[]
  },
  { 
    id: 2,
    Index: 2,
    ResponsiveStyle: 3,
    Widgets: []

  }
];

var Columns = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  schema: {
    data: "Columns"

  }
});

var Rows = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  schema: {
    data: "Rows",
    model: rowModel
  }
});

var Widgets = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  schema: {
    data: "Widgets",
    model: layoutWidgetModel
  }
});

var layoutWidgetModel = kendo.data.Node.define({
  id: "layoutWidget",
  hasChildren: "Rows",
  children: Rows
});

var rowModel = kendo.data.Node.define({
  id: "rowModel",
  hasChildren: "Columns",
  children: Columns
});


var parentModel = kendo.data.Node.define({
  id: "parentModel",
  hasChildren: "Widgets",
  children: Widgets
});


var validator;
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
//create a dataSource
  dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: initColumns,

    schema: {
      model: parentModel
    }

  }),

  selected: {} //this field will contain the edited dataItem

});

viewModel.dataSource.read(); //invoke the read transport of the DataSource

//Create the variables to create an object for insertion into the main parent object for the HierarchicalDataSource
var Rows = [ { Index: 0, Columns: [
    {
    Index: 0,
    ResponsiveStyle: 0
  }]
} ];
var SubType = 'Joined';
var WidgetName = 'widget name';
    var Type = 'widget type';
    var DisplayType = 'widget subtype';
    var Title = 'widget title';
var Collapsible = true;
var Borders = 1;
var TitleBackground = 4;
var TitleColour = 6;

var kendoLayoutWidget = new layoutWidgetModel({ Title: Title, Type: Type, SubType: SubType, WidgetName: WidgetName, Collapsible: Collapsible, DisplayType: DisplayType, Borders: Borders, TitleBackground: TitleBackground, TitleColour: TitleColour, Rows: Rows });

//Get the uid of the new widget
var GUID = kendoLayoutWidget.uid;

//Get the current object from the HierarchicalDataSource
var VBdata = viewModel.dataSource.data();

//Push in the newly created widget object
VBdata[0].Widgets.push(kendoLayoutWidget);

//Replace the old data in the dataSource with the new multilevel object
viewModel.dataSource.data(VBdata);

//find the layoutwidget by getByUid()
var theWidget = viewModel.dataSource.getByUid(GUID);
console.log(viewModel.dataSource);
console.log(GUID);
console.log(theWidget);
```

Comment: `getByUid()` searches only through `dataSource.data()` items, but you trying to search through `dataSource.data()[0].Widgets` items

Comment: According to the dcumentation:  The remove and getByUid methods are overridden and work with the hierarchical data (they will act on all child datasources that have been read). To me that sounds like it should work on child nodes of the dataSource

Comment: The name of children in schema must be quoted: `children: "Widgets"`

Comment: @GeneRI don't think so - that refers to the instantiated hierarchical datasources. I did find out that these don't need to be data sources, and rather should simply be a normal JavaScript object.

Comment: I mean`schema.model.children` definition. Check example: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/hierarchicaldatasource#configuration-schema.model.children

Comment: Mine is the same as that, just by way of different syntax and construction - the 'children' in my defined Nodes are referencing the dataSource variables, and in those the 'data' property references, in quotation marks, the name of the field in which the children items are found.